# How to secure Firebase Messaging topics with cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to secure validate subscriptions to topics? For example, is it possible to limit topic Test to a specific user with ID XXXXX? Is this possible with Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

To be able to subscribe to a topic, you currently need to know two things: the FCM token/instance ID of the app instance, and the path/name of the topic to subscribe to.

Knowing these two allows one to subscribe to the topic from any client. There currently is no public API to limit who can subscribe to what topics. So if you need to guarantee that the message is only delivered to authorized app instances, you should not use topics and instead delivery to each FCM token/instance ID directly from your own (server-side) code.

This request comes along regularly though, so I recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add your vote.

Comment: I find it very annoying that firebase doesnt allow you to send a notification to all devices logged in on user x@example.com, or specify them by their UID. I will definitely make a request for this.